# How to get subtitle from firebase push notification

Tags: android, firebase, android-intent, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am getting push notification in this format from server.

```
{
                title: messageTitle,
                body: messageBody,
               subtitle: messageSubtitle
}
```

In my android project i read notification by using following code.

```
remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle();
remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody();
```

The above 2 lines gives me `Title` and `Body`, but i am unable to understand how to read `subtitle` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard notification format does not include **subtitle** hence there is no method to fetch it, to get a subtitle message please use ***data*** key.

> Standard Notification format

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    }
  }
}
```

if you want a subtitle please add subtitle to data field and then then fetch using getData() method

> Customized Notification for subtitle

```
{
  "message":{
    "token":"bk3RNwTe3H0:CI2k_HHwgIpoDKCIZvvDMExUdFQ3P1...",
    "notification":{
      "title":"Portugal vs. Denmark",
      "body":"great match!"
    },
    "data" : {
      "subtitle" : "Mario",
      "subHeading" : "PortugalVSDenmark"
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

//remoteMessage is reference of RemoteMessage

```
 `val data = remoteMessage.data

    if(data.isNotEmpty())
    {

        if (data.containsKey("title"))
            title = data["title"].toString()

        if (data.containsKey("body"))
            body = data["path"].toString()

        if(data.containsKey("subtitle"))
            subtitle = data["subtitle"].toString()

        if(data.containsKey("notifyId"))
            notifyId = data["notifyId"]?.toInt()

        }`
```

Answer (score 0):

To recieve FCM notifications with custom data, we need to check the data payloads as follows:-

- When in the background, apps receive the notification payload in the
  notification tray, and only handle the data payload when the user
  taps on the notification.
- When in the foreground, your app receives a
  message object with both payloads available.

  In case 2 , you can simply check as below:-

  `String customData = remoteMessage.getData().get("customData");`

And for the first case please refer to the answer;-

[handle notification with custom data](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39149287/7200713)

Hope this helps.